# php javascript partial page reload

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page set-up, with several divs.
For now all we need is

```
<div id="main">...</div> & <div id="sidebar">...</div>
```

Each div has code such as:

```
<?php include("page.php") ?>
```

The main div does all the work, and includes a JavaScript function. E.g. at the moment the user can click a button to remember an item displayed in a table.

Am I able to only reload the sidebar instead of the whole page when the user calls this function?
I am posting the function here, and all I need now is to be able to refresh the sidepanel and its included php files if that is possible? I assume something along the lines of this could do the job? or am I wrong? `load("#sidebar")`

```
function saveToFavorites(code)
{

    $.ajax({
        async:false,
        type: "POST",
        url: 'formPostsUser.php?reqtype=addToFavorite',
        data:'coursecode='+ code,
        success: function(data) 
        {
            $('.result').html(data);
            if(data != "")
            {
                alert(data);
                load("#sidebar") 
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Kind regards
Alex

Happy about any and every reply and hint ;)

Comment: `<div="sidebar">` is not valid. try `<div id="sidebar">`

Comment: thats not the point here -> it was quick writing. I am asking about the script necessary to partialy load pages - laoding divs or included php files. I have edited the question to avoid confusion

Comment: That absolutely is the point here! How can you expect us to help you if your posting code that doesn't reflect the **actual** code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing

```
 <div="sidebar">..</div>
```

The above markup is wrong HTML. You should give the sidebar as the value of your properties such as id or class

```
<div id="sidebar">..</div>
```

**Loading the Sidebar content**

You can use jQuery ajax to load content of this div using jQuery [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method like this

```
$(function(){
  $("#sidebar").load("yourPHPPageToReturnSideBarContent.php");  
});
```

Assuming `yourPHPPageToReturnSideBarContent.php` is the PHP page which renders the HTML Markkup for the sidebar. Note that this will load the content on the [document ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event.

**Loading the side bar content on an event**

If you want to load it on a purticular event like a button click you can do it like this

```
$(function(){
  $(document).on("click","yourButtonId",function(){
     $("#sidebar").load("yourPHPPageToReturnSideBarContent.php");  
   });
});
```

The above script will load the side bar content on a button click. The button's id is e "yourButtonId" in this example.

Note that i used [jQuery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) here to bind the function because it will take care of current element and future element in case if you want to load the markup which contains the button dynamically.

Comment: ok, nearly there. It does seem simple. However, I seem to have an issue with the fact that under my sidebar div, I include a php file, which again includes 2 diff files. So at the moment It looses all other data, and only displays the loaded php page. Any idea how to overcome this ?

Comment: then you specify that purticular div where you want to load, as the id  instead of sidebar. Ex : ` $("#subDivInside").load(yoururl) `

Comment: these are all included php files depedning on the URL parameters. All within Side bar div

Comment: i guess it does the job, just have to restructure the side bar unfortunately. thx bud